# What if I migrate an AWS standalone account to Organizations?

Tags: amazon-web-services

At work, we have an AWS standalone account which have been created some time ago by the IT Department and inside we have some users created. Now we want to move to AWS Organizations because the consolidated billing and the possibility of apply ACL across multiple users.

My question is: What happen with the already running services that have been created via the standalone account (e.g, API Gateways, Lambda functions, S3 buckets and EC2 instances) when we switch to Organizations format?

The answer to this question change if we create a new account and then invite our already old account to the new organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: What happen with the already running services that
> have been created via the standalone account (e.g, API Gateways,
> Lambda functions, S3 buckets and EC2 instances) when we switch to
> Organizations format?

There won't be any impact for the existing services under your account unless you enable Service Control Policies and attach a restrictive policy to the AWS account, where existing users won't be able to perform restricted actions (By default, Service Control Policies are Disabled in Organizations). Only noticeable thing is, the billing will be consolidated to the root account. You can even detach the account from the organization, later if needed.

> The answer to this question change if we create a new account and then
> invite our already old account to the new organization?

There is a difference when creating a new account under the organization vs inviting an already existing account to become a part of an organization. The main difference is, when you create a new account under the organization, the account cannot be detached from the organization later on.

> **Tutorial:** You can find a complete guide by referring to the [AWS Organizations Hands-on!](https://youtu.be/jtKqYM9GjNM) video tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Organizations is just an account management tool- it doesn't affect the resources *within* an account. So, to answer your question: your resources will stay as they are after you switch to Organizations.